# When HDFS starts, why not load local editsLog and then load editsLog on QJM? Instead, only loaded on QJM editsLog?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I created three virtual machines on windows, used to build hadoop2.6 high availability cluster for learning, after a period of time, through the webui interface to see hdfs start and did not load the local editsLog, but loaded QJM Cluster, I am sure there is editsLog local, with QJM on the same, but what does it mean? If the local lack of editsLog, will certainly be to QJM cluster load, do not understand, hdfs default configuration editsLog not only write local, but also write the intention of QJM, since QJM editsLOg shared, and loading only loaded QJM cluster editsLog , Then the local editsLog has become a decoration?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEGj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior will depend on your exact configurations. I suspect that you have configured the QJM as the `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir` and left `dfs.namenode.edits.dir` as a local directory (or blank, in which case it will use the value of `dfs.namenode.name.dir`). The shared edits dir will be used as the source of truth.

In general if you configure a QJM you should consider that to be your source of truth for your HA cluster. Additional edit logs are just a backup. This is important because in a failover scenario (changing your active NameNode), the new active (previous standby) may not have the edits available locally, so it *must* go through the QJM to determine what edits are required to be applied.

It is a little annoying that `dfs.namenode.edits.dir` must be specified even when a shared edits dir is configured (as of 3.0.0); to get around this you can set its value to match that of `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir`, effectively disabling local edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your answer let me suddenly enlightened, So this dfs.namenode.edits.dir defaults to Dfs.tmp.dir Dfs.namenode.name.dir, Dfs.tmp.dir is a must be configured, otherwise initialization will fail, then I can think this is a historical legacy of hadoop1.x, in Hadoop 1.x, edits is local, can configure multiple directory implementation redundancy, after Ha, instead of QJM storage, QJM has implemented redundancy, but did not remove the local configuration, perhaps to avoid the upgrade from 1.x to the HA process trouble?

Comment: I am assuming by `dfs.tmp.dir` you meant `hadoop.tmp.dir`.

In Hadoop 2+, you may still want local edits, e.g. HDFS is not always run in HA mode and in that case you would want local edits. You may also want to have local edits for extra redundancy (perhaps sending to some backup storage). So I would not consider `dfs.namenode.edits.dir` a "legacy" configuration. However it is a little annoying that it must be specified even when shared edits is configured; to get around this you can sets its value to match that of `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir`, effectively disabling local edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I know what you mean.